# Tab Navigation on Virtualized Items Panel

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, silverlight

How can you set the Tab Navigation on virtualized items? As example;

```
        <ListBox x:Name="Items">        
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsPresenter/>           
                    </ScrollViewer>         
                </ControlTemplate>      
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>         
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>       
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
             <Button />
                </DataTemplate>         
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>           
        </ListBox>
```

If I set TabNavigation=Once or Cycle on the Scrollviewer itself, or the Listbox parent etc, it only tabs through items available in the viewport since the others haven't been generated yet. Is there a trick someone might share for when tabbing through Item Objects it will allow Tab to proceed to the next not-yet-virtualized item while bringing it to view in the viewport and providing intuitive tabbing through the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what was came up (thanks to the extra eyes and help of another fine dev) with was to go ahead and render the other items but while remaining virtualized from onload with a custom behavior and at the same time exposing a dependency for continuous scrolling and bringing the current item into view in the viewport;

```
namespace The.Namespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows;   
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    /// <summary>
    /// Scroll selected item into view.
    /// </summary>
    public class ListBoxFocusBehavior : FocusBehavior<ListBox>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsContinuousProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsContinuous",
                                                                         typeof(bool),
                                                                         typeof(ListBoxFocusBehavior),
                                                                         new PropertyMetadata(
                                                                             false,
                                                                             (d, e) => ((ListBoxFocusBehavior)d).IsContinuousScroll = (bool)e.NewValue));
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is continuous.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        ///      <c>true</c> if this instance is continuous; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </value>
        public bool IsContinuous
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsContinuousProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsContinuousProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Called after the behavior is attached to an AssociatedObject.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += SelectionChanged;
            AssociatedObject.KeyDown += KeyDown;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Keys down.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
            {
               //forward tab ...
                var idx = AssociatedObject.Items.IndexOf(AssociatedObject.SelectedItem);
                if (idx < AssociatedObject.Items.Count-1)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = AssociatedObject.Items[idx + 1];
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
            {
                //back tab.
                var idx = AssociatedObject.Items.IndexOf(AssociatedObject.SelectedItem);
                if (idx > 0)
                {
                    AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = AssociatedObject.Items[idx - 1];
                    e.Handled = true;
                }

            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the behavior is being detached from its AssociatedObject, but before it has actually occurred.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= SelectionChanged;
            AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= KeyDown;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gots the focus.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AssociatedObject.SelectedItem == null && AssociatedObject.Items.Any())
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = AssociatedObject.Items.First();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Selections the changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The sender.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        private void SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AssociatedObject.SelectedItem == null) return;
            AssociatedObject.UpdateLayout();

            //have to, otherwise the listbox will probably not focus.
            Action setFocus = () =>
                                  {
                                      AssociatedObject.UpdateLayout();                                     
                                      AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(AssociatedObject.SelectedItem);
                                      //ensure that if the container did not exist yet (virtualized), it gets created.
                                      AssociatedObject.UpdateLayout();   
                                      var container =
                                         AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(
                                             AssociatedObject.SelectedItem) as Control;
                                      if (container != null)
                                      {
                                          container.Focus();
                                      }

                                  };
            AssociatedObject.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(setFocus);
        }
    }
}
```